# Booting with a bunch of "read-only file system" messages

Tags: linux

I have been tring to make my system dual-bootable. So I installed lilo and put it in my MBR. It loads and gives me this bunch of "Read-only file system" messages in the startup messages. Then I get a TTY. I can cat my files, but can not change anything, and I can not open any of my application programs.

Here is my lilo .conf file

```
       boot=/dev/sda

       image = /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-2-generic
       label="Linux"
       root=/dev/sda2
       read-only
       initrd = /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-2-generic
```

and here is my fstab file

```
       - /etc/fstab: static file system information.

      # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
      # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
      # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
      # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
          proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
      # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
         UUID=7c37411f-3ff6-4de2-b35b-5f3605ad7ad5 /               ext4      
        errors=remount-ro 0       1
       # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
       UUID=db9f8da7-ef2a-4298-8457-15d9eb4a51e0 none            swap    
        sw              0       0
```

Comment: What OS'es are you trying to dual-boot? What is your partition layout?

Comment: no sorry i am not installing other OS just two linux kernels

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not recommend using lilo. Is there any reason you are not using `grub2`? Nothing wrong with lilo mind, just not so popular these days.

Anyway, removing the `read-only` line from your lilo.conf should do the trick.

Another problem is that your lilo.conf points to `/dev/sda2` as root, while your `fstab` has `/dev/sda1` as root.

I could probably help more if you include the actual error messages you are getting.

Comment: r u sure it also says that the drive / is not ready yet or is not present.continue to wait or s to skip or m...."

Comment: No, I'm not sure but it should be a start. At least for the read-only problem. I really would use grub2 instead of lilo though, it is much better for modern OSs.

Comment: Nothing wrong with lilo. It has a single configuration file, fits within an MBR.  GRUB2 is bloated beyond belief.

Comment: @fpmurphy, there is absolutely nothing wrong with lilo, I used it happily for years. I do find grub2 easier to configure, prettier and more powerful though. Plus, since it is now the standard for most distributions it is easier to find help for it.

Comment: @micflinulu, see updated answer.

Comment: well for ur information deleting the read-only line doesn,t change any thing

Comment: @micflinulu, did you also change sda2 to sda1? For more specific help you will need to give us the error messages you are getting.

Comment: the thing is when the system boots there is no user interface just command prompt.And when i for example enter "sudo gedit /etc/lilo.conf" it says can not open display

Comment: @micflinulu, yes `gedit` needs a running X server, try a command line editor like `nano` instead.